# Importing Woocommerce products with variations

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, bulk-import

I need a plugin or script which will help me import woo commerce products along with variations and respective prices,descriptions and quantities. Is it possible to use a simple plugin or a combination of plugin to achieve this. as reference script with minor changes also will help.

Comment: You don't need a plugin for this: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-importer-exporter/

Comment: ok will try this thanks jacob

Answer (score 1):

still,users who also search for a solution to ease WooCommerce site management, including [import of valiables](https://woocommerce-manager.com/useful-articles/woocommerce-product-management/woocommerce-import-variable-products-tutorial/), can consider Store Manager and its trial version for testing